# Highlighting YAML comments correctly

Tags: major-mode, syntax-highlighting, syntax-table

See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-12/msg01046.html for more background.

YAML defines a comment as a `#` either preceded by the beginning of the line or whitespace (more specifically, `TAB` or `SPC`).  This means that `foo#bar` is a normal token, not `foo` with a `#bar` comment.  You can get most of the way there with the traditional syntax rules:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?# "<")
(modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">")
```

Unfortunately this will highlight `foo#bar` incorrectly.  I've been pointed to `syntax-propertize-function` which allows for more powerful syntax rules, but behaves weirdly.  Depending on the specific code I write, either insertion of new characters or deletion invalidates the existing fontification.

Example 1 (marking `#` preceded by non-whitespace as `_`):

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?# "<")
(modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">")

;; invalidated by deletion
(syntax-propertize-rules
  ("[^ \t]#" (0 "_")))
```

Example 2 (marking `#` preceded by whitespace as `<`):

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">")

;; invalidated by insertion
(syntax-propertize-rules
  ("^#" (0 "<")))
  ("[ \t]#" (0 "<")))
```

If I rewrite either of these in terms of a function scanning for appliable parts and edebug it, edebug does *not* take me through the function for the invalidating case.  Any idea why?

Bonus - Syntax propertize functions:

Example 1:

```
(defun yaml-mode-syntax-propertize-function (beg end)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char beg)
    (while (search-forward "#" end t)
      (save-excursion
        (forward-char -2) ;; move to char preceding #
        (when (looking-at "[^ \t]")
          (forward-char 1) ;; move to # again
          (put-text-property (point) (1+ (point))
                             'syntax-table (string-to-syntax "_"))))))
```

Example 2:

```
(defun yaml-mode-syntax-propertize-function (beg end)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char beg)
    (while (search-forward "#" end t)
      (save-excursion
        (forward-char -1)
        (if (bolp)
            (put-text-property (point) (1+ (point))
                               'syntax-table (string-to-syntax "<"))
          (forward-char -1)
          (when (looking-at "[ \t]")
            (forward-char 1)
            (put-text-property (point) (1+ (point))
                               'syntax-table (string-to-syntax "<"))))))))
```

Test file:

```
keyword: token#token
#comment comment
token #comment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yaml-mode` adds a function to the obsolete variable `font-lock-syntactic-keywords`. It appears as though this interferes with syntactic propertize functions.

My suggestion is to combine the two into one and only use the modern `syntax-propertize-function` method.

Btw. your first example works (when `font-lock-syntactic-keywords` isn't set), but you need to check if the `#` is at the beginning of a line:

```
(defun yaml-mode-syntax-propertize-function (beg end)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char beg)
    (while (search-forward "#" end t)
      (save-excursion
        (forward-char -1)
        (unless (bolp)
          (forward-char -1)           ;; move to char preceding #
          (when (looking-at "[^ \t]")
            (forward-char 1) ;; move to # again
            (put-text-property (point) (1+ (point))
                               'syntax-table (string-to-syntax "_"))))))))
```

Also, it can be made more efficient if you use something like `(memq (preceding-char) '(?\s ?\t))`, as in:

```
(defun yaml-mode-syntax-propertize-function (beg end)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char beg)
    (while (search-forward "#" end t)
      (save-excursion
        (forward-char -1)
        (unless (bolp)
          (unless (memq (preceding-char) '(?\s ?\t))
            (put-text-property (point) (1+ (point))
                               'syntax-table (string-to-syntax "_"))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't have expected *that* to interfere, but once I removed the change to that variable, no more invalidation happens.